# Button tag not displaying any elements such as text etc

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am trying to implement a simple button using angular materials, I have imported the needed module into the respective module which im consuming the component. But it is displaying as below, I have tried also implementing a normal button without angular material and the same thing happens.
[image: enter image desNOTE: the right bubble is the button, the phrase text is just a p tag outside the button.cription here]

I tried adding normal html buttons.
Checked the imports are importing correctly.

Comment: Could you provide your code or even better a https://stackblitz.com/ sample ?

Comment: I tried to implement it on stackblitz, all though I couldn't replicate. Found the culprit, issue was as I had a component with the tag 'button' that displayed nothing therefore, it was calling that component rather than the basic of html.